# Purpose of SourceFiles flag while generating Jacoco Reports using Jacoco CLI?

Tags: jacoco

What is the advantage of using --sourcefiles flag while generating jacoco reports using jacoco cli jar vs when not using it?

Reference: https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html

Task: Report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the difference you can try with and without this option. For example:

Given following `src/org/example/Example.java`

```
package org.example;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

After compilation and execution by

```
javac src/org/example/Example.java -d classes
java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.5/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp classes org.example.Example
```

---

Generation of report **without `--sourcefiles`**

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.5/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes --html report_without_sourcefiles
```

will produce report in directory `report_without_sourcefiles` where **you can not see source file**

[image: report]

[image: report for package]

[image: report for class]

---

While generation of report **with `--sourcefiles`**

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.5/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes --sourcefiles src --html report_with_sourcefiles
```

will produce report in directory `report_with_sourcefiles` where **you can see source file**

[image: report]

[image: report for package]

[image: report for class]

[image: report for source file]