# JaCoCo does not show the source files in the HTML coverage report for multi projects

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, eclipse-pde

I'm using PDE and in my build.xml I compile my code and try to create a coverage report using JaCoCo and JUnit. I noticed that it does now show the sourcefile, even though I added `sourcefiles` section in the `structure` section of `jacoco:report`. In order to debug it (because it does not prints any errors), I tried to run it [locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885853/purpose-of-sourcefiles-flag-while-generating-jacoco-reports-using-jacoco-cli):

```
java -jar jacoco/jacococli.jar report /buildFiles/coverage/jacoco.exec --classfiles /buildFiles/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/bin/com/gandu/da/util/test/AllTests.class --sourcefiles /buildFiles/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/src/com/gandu/da/util/test/AllTests.java --html html_report
```

But it still does not show the sourcecode in the html file. In the [official JaCoCo FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html) I see:

> Why does the coverage report not show highlighted source code?
> Make sure the following prerequisites are fulfilled to get source code highlighting in JaCoCo coverage reports:
>
> - Class files must be compiled with debug information to contain line numbers.
> - Source files must be properly supplied at report generation time. I.e. specified source folders must be the direct parent of the folders that define the Java packages.

I compiled the code with `-g` flag to get all the information - it didn't work. Also I believe that I do supply the src/bin files as expected so I'm not sure why it does not work. How to make it work?

**EDIT**: I had to provide the `src` directory:

```
java -jar jacoco/jacococli.jar report /buildFiles/coverage/jacoco.exec --classfiles /buildFiles/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/bin/com/gandu/da/util/test/AllTests.class --sourcefiles /buildFiles/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/src
# WORKED!
```

Now I want to fix the issue with my build.xml. The code:

```
<jacoco:report>
    <executiondata>
        <file file="${coverage.file}"/>
    </executiondata>
    <structure name="Coverage Report">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/bin">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>
    
    <html destdir="${coverage.html}"/>
</jacoco:report>
```

This code worked and it provided the coverage report **with the source files**. But as you can see I had to hardcoded only one package (`com.gandu.da.util.test`). I want to create a coverage report from all the packages that:

- src: `${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu*/src`.
- bin: `${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu*/bin`.

So I tried:

```
<jacoco:report>
    <executiondata>
        <file file="${coverage.file}"/>
    </executiondata>
    <structure name="Coverage Report">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.*/bin">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.*/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>
    
    <html destdir="${coverage.html}"/>
</jacoco:report>
```

But it didn't work because the path (with the star) does not exist. It makes sense because `dir` expects to get one path. So I figured that `<foreach>` might help here but after reading the [docs](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/foreach.html), I could not figure a way to use it. The above code is what I need. I hope to hear a suggestion on how to solve this.

One more note since it's important: the structure of source and class files:

- source files are located under `${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu*/src`.
- class files are located under: `${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu*/bin`.

I also tried to insert `${buildDirectory}/plugins` in `dir` of both `<classfiles>` and `<sourcefiles>` but it didn't work. It does create the coverage report but it does not show the source files. I guess I need to provide the `src` dir of each package.

So I thought to use `<foreach>` to insert each package into the structure. I might need to use `jacoco:merge` to merge them, but I'm not sure.

Also tried `includes="**/usr/**` and `includes="**/bin/**`.

I also have a few different ant version I could use here. might help? Also, maybe I could "hardcode" the plugins somehow and "merge" the reports?

**EDIT**: It looked like it worked when you provide multi plugins like so:

```
<jacoco:report>
    <!--  This task needs the collected execution data and ...  -->
    <executiondata>
        <file file="${coverage.metadata.file}"/>
    </executiondata>
    <!--  the class files and optional source files ...  -->
    <structure name="JaCoCo Coverage Report">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.mangager.test/@dot">
                 <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.alltests/@dot">
                 <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.mangager.test/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.alltests/src">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
    </structure>
    
    <html destdir="${coverage.html.dir}"/>
    <csv destfile="${coverage.csv.file}"/>
    <xml destfile="${coverage.xml.file}"/>
</jacoco:report>
```

Is it possible to maybe put all the wanted names (like `com.gandu.da.util.alltests`) into a file, read them one by one, and run `for` (or `foreach`) on them and add them as `fileset` maybe (after you append each one with the path)?

Comment: It's not that this answers the question, but have you already considered using a more modern build management tool like e.g. Maven (or if you really must Gradle)? There would be the [JaCoCo Maven Plug-in](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) which works in a (n>1)⋅10⁵ LOC project here like a charm.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Unfortunately it's a legacy tool which needed PDE and Eclipse 4.8 (its built on Eclipse) so it's not possible to move to Maven/Gradle at the moment.

Comment: It have been a few days since I added the bounty. Maybe I need to add additional information for you? Just let me know in the comments

Comment: Your title and the first few paragraphs still reflect your first question, about including source files, but I think you are now asking a second question about including multiple projects in a single JaCoCo report, right? You might get better answers if you cleared that up. GL!

Comment: @Rich its the same project but I have a few packages in that project. All start with `/com.gandu.*`. My first question was about the JaCoCo CLI because I described the issue in the first paragraph and it was a debugging attempt. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: could you run ant with diagnostic flags- it will print more information why particular directory is not seen.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not meeting one of the declared preconditions:

> specified source folders must be the direct parent of the folders that define the Java packages

```
--sourcefiles /buildFiles/plugins/com.gandu.da.util.test/src
```

Gradle might be a whole lot more script-able than the CLI or Maven is.

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that your includes are handled correctly by changing:

```
<include name="**/*.class" />
```

...to...

```
includes ="**/*.class"
```

...and...

```
<include name="**/*.java" />
```

...to...

```
includes ="**/*.java"
```

PS: Having trouble with the editor accepting each alternate in code brackets.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't solve the issue. Still does not show the source files in the coverage report.